# find a min value by iterating the array and dividing each element by a number starting with 1

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a below method which iterates a distance array and divide each element by a number starting with 1 and get the sum. If sum is greater than value `points` which is passed to the method then start again in the for loop and divide by 2 and keep going until you find a sum which is less than value `points`.

Below code works but is there any way to write this better?

```
  public static int findMin(List<Integer> distance, int points) {
    int sum = 0;
    int c = 1;
    while (true) {
      for (Integer dist : distance) {
        sum = (int) (sum + Math.ceil(dist / c));
      }
      if (sum <= points) {
        break;
      }
      c++;
      sum = 0;
    }
    return c;
  }
```

Comment: Please update your question clarifying the requirement to have the `Math.ceil` operation and correct your usage of integer division when you mean to use non-integer division.

Comment: You can avoid `Math.ceil` and use of floating point math. Use the modulo operator to determine whether there is a remainder, and use that to adjust the sum. So instead of `sum = (int)(sum + Math.ceil(dist / c));` the code would be `sum += dist / c; if (dist % c) sum++;`

Comment: Can you say more about the data? What is the range of values `points` and each `dist` can take and how many `dist`s?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no specific reason to do Math.ceil to each ratio rather than to the final sum, you can just get the sum of all elements first and then find the value of c

sum / c <= points

sum / points <= c

if 0 < (sum / points) < 1, c = 1

else c = Math.ceil(sum / points)

Comment: I'm confused. Shouldn't `findMin([8], 3) = 3` and `findMin([4,4], 3) = 4` ? That would make this answer wrong as it would return 3 for both cases.

Comment: OP is doing Math.ceil(int/int) which is equivalent to int/int. It was not clear whether that ceil operation is required. So that's why I stated 
"If there is no specific reason to do Math.ceil to each ratio rather than to the final sum" you can follow the above approach. Yes, this wrong if the OP intended for Math.ceil(float/float) or plain int/int.

Comment: Ah, oops, I missed that qualification in your answer, sorry :) But isn't int/int equivalent to floor(int/int) rather than ceil?

Comment: Yes. It is but only for positive values. floor(-12.0/5.0) = -3.0 whereas -12/5 = 2

Comment: Actually, the OP clarified and didn't mean to imply they were doing integer math. So that `ceil` is a very important operation, as it's intended to be operating on real numbers. "Basically ceil(5/2) should be 3 or ceil(7/2) should be 4. That's the requirement. Did I use wrong function in Java to round up the number? Looks like I did" (from OP in response to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int findMin(List<Integer> distance, int points) {
    AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(1);
    while (distance.stream().mapToInt(d -> d / c.get()).sum() > points) c.incrementAndGet();
    return c.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but assuming the set of distances is `[1, 2, 3]` right? Then you start with `1/1 + 2/1 + 3/1` which (let's leave them as fractions here) equals `6/1`, since they all have the same "denominator" here, it doesn't change. So that means that the first iteration, dividing by one, is literally the sum of the values. `(1 + 2 + 3) / 1` divided by one. And anything divided by 1 is itself. So it's just the sum.

Now. On the second pass, if I assume correctly, `1/2 + 2/2 + 3/2` -- again leaving them as fractions -- `(1 + 2 + 3) / 2` = `6/2`. By now you should see a pattern, right? First pass was `6/1` second is `6/2` next will be `6/3`...

So how about:

```
public static int findMin(List<Integer> distance, int points) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer i : distance) {
        sum += i;
    }

    int min = 1;
    while (sum / min > points) {
        min += 1;
    }

    return min;
}
```

Perhaps a solution like this would work?

**edit** So as it turns out this solution is assuming (at least partially) some mathematical accuracy, however it appears that the division per-element is required to be integer division which skews some of the results if we approach it strictly mathematically. So while not being a direct answer to the problem I feel like it's correct enough to leave here as a solution.

Comment: I believe the sum on the second pass is 1+1+2 = 4. The OP appears to be doing integer division, rounded up.

Comment: Without clarification that that is due to a requirement (it's unclear) I'm sticking with my answer.

Comment: Yes doing integer division and need to round up so thats why using Math.ceil.

Comment: `Math.ceil` on integer division is a no-op. `3 / 2` is 1, not 1.5, so `Math.ceil(3 / 2)` is `Math.ceil(1)`.

Comment: No it will be 2

Comment: Basically ceil(5/2) should be 3 or ceil(7/2) should be 4. That's the requirement. Did I use wrong function in Java to round up the number? Looks like I did.

Comment: @UserX No, 3 and 2 are integers (as the two variables are), and `3 / 2 == 1` following integer division as the remainder is discarded. Only after the expression is calculated is the result then sent to `Math.ceil` and treated as a `double`, so the result is actually `1.0`, which is already "ceiled" so to speak. Refer to this: https://ideone.com/cq7GKK

Comment: @flash Integer division does not deal with remainders, so if you want `3 / 2 == 1.5` (mathematically correct) so that `Math.ceil` produces a `2` here then you need to cast one of those integers to a double so that you use a more precise division operation. Otherwise, `Math.ceil(3 / 2) == Math.ceil(1) == 1`

Comment: @BrandonBuck so how can I get `(5/2)` division as 3 in Java? Because I need to round this up to the next integer if the value modulo `1 != 0`.

Comment: @flash One of your operands needs to be a double to trigger double division instead of integer division. Like `Math.ceil((double)dist / c)` or something.

Comment: sum(3,5,7,9)/2 = 12, but sum(3/2,5/2,7/2,9/2)=10

Comment: @TongChen Pleas refer to my **edit** note. I'm aware this doesn't solve the problem. Also `sum(ceil(3/2), ceil(5/2), ceil(7/2), ceil(9/2)) == sum(ceil(1.5), ceil(2.5), ceil(3.5), ceil(4.5)) == sum(2, 3, 4,5) == 14`

Comment: Binary search for that `min` value?

Comment: @vivek_23 binary search would work providing the values are all positive or possibly also if each negative value has a significantly greater (when comparing absolute values) positive counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

I think，we can do two things to improve the performance,but the method is not the best and it depend on the number of your list:

- reduce the times of iterate
- use greedy algorithm priority reduction the max value. In order to do this we first need to sort the list it cost may cost O(nlog(n)) time.

code like this

```
public static int findMin(List<Integer> distance, int points) {
    int sum = 0;
    int c = 1;
    // sort the list for implement greedy algorithm
    Collections.sort(distance, Comparator.reverseOrder());
    while (true) {
        for (Integer dist : distance) {
            sum += dist / c;
            // reduce the times of iterate
            if (sum <= points) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        c++;
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: As discussed as part of my answer, the `Math.ceil` is significant to finding the correct answer and it seems like the use of integer division in generating a sum was erroneous. So you might want to modify your answer with that in mind.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this returns an incorrect answer. If I pass in `[1, 2, 3]` and `3`, expecting to get `3` back as an answer (as `⌈1/2⌉ + ⌈2/2⌉ +⌈3/2⌉ = ⌈0.5⌉ + ⌈1⌉ + ⌈1.5⌉ = 1 + 1 + 2 = 4` and `⌈1/3⌉ + ⌈2/3⌉ + ⌈3/3⌉ = ⌈0.34⌉ + ⌈0.67⌉ + ⌈1⌉ = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3` and `3 <= 3`). If I feed that input to your algorithm it gets to the first line in the inner-most loop `sum = 0 + (3 / 1)` so `sum == 3` and `3 <= points` so you return `1`? That's not correct.

Comment: Maybe you meant `if (sum > points)` in that inner most test? Even still the return is incorrect. That should break out and move on?